# getStream Chat Api response in iOS

Tags: ios, getstream-io

Can we get json from getStream chat Api response? that we can use in our own data modal and create custom UI? I am using getStream chat iOS sdk.  querying for channel data. getting response as channelResponse

```
let query = ChannelsQuery(filter: .equal("type", to: "messaging") & .in("members", ["9"]),
                                      pagination: [.limit(1)], messagesLimit: [.limit(1)] )
            Client.shared.queryChannels(query: query) { (result) in

            }
```

Comment: You might be looking for REST docs: https://getstream.io/chat/docs_rest/

Comment: I am trying to implement Rest APIs provided by GetStream. So, I put the baseUrl and expected headers in following ways :

    Request Url     : https://chat-us-east-1.stream-io-api.com/channeltypes

These are the values which I put in Headers section of Postman :

    Authorization   : <Getstream token from backend>
    Stream-Auth-Type: jwt
    api_key         : <Getstream API key>

But I am not getting this response :

> {
    "code": 17,
    "ListChannelTypes failed with error: \"Channel types can be described only with server-side auth\"",

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132187/how-to-use-getstream-rest-api-to-get-response-in-postman