# How to use Getstream Rest API to get response in Postman?

Tags: ios, rest, postman, chat, getstream-io

I am trying to implement Stream chat Rest APIs ( by following this link : https://getstream.io/chat/docs_rest ) provided by GetStream. So, I put the baseUrl and expected headers in following ways :

```
Request Url     : https://chat-us-east-1.stream-io-api.com/channeltypes
```

These are the values which I put in Headers section of Postman :

```
Authorization   : <Getstream token (generating from setUser function) from backend>
Stream-Auth-Type: jwt
api_key         : <Getstream API key>
```

But I am getting this response on hitting API on Postman:

> {
>       "code": 17,
>       "message": "ListChannelTypes failed with error: \"Channel types can be described only with server-side auth\"",
>       "StatusCode": 403,
>       "duration": "0.00ms"
>   }

I am unable to find out what I am missing or doing wrong in using the **Rest API of Getstream**. Please suggest and help in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As described in error message:

> Channel types can be described only with server-side auth

It's only possible with server side authentication.

When you use `Authorization: <Getstream token (generating from setUser function) from backend>`, this is for client-side.

You need to use your secret in the token to enable server-side and to gueary in this endpoint.

Comment: I am using the JWT generator in their docs, https://getstream.io/chat/docs/token_generator/?language=js, to get a token, which uses the secret, but i'm still getting the above error?